# Does Laravel use Prepared Statements by default?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm somewhat new to Laravel and this is just a quick question, does Laravel use prepared statements by default so I don't have to worry about using them?  Basically, does this statement (to use the example from the Laravel website):

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', array(1, 'Dayle'));
```

use prepared statements automatically?  Or if I want the security that comes with prepared statements will I have to do them manually?  It seems like it does because of the question marks where where the values would be but I just wanted to double check before just making that assumption and making an unnecessary security mistake.

Comment: @RahilWazir - Please don't link to the old Laravel 3 docs. Thank you.

Comment: @JosephSilber Does it matter? Laravel 4 doesn't use prepared statements? :)

Comment: @RahilWazir - We don't want people to get in the habit of visiting the old docs.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Connection.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php).

Search for the insert method which eventually will leads you to:

```
$statement = $me->getPdo()->prepare($query);
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent