# Why `having` only worked on fields that are `group by` on laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, having

My script laravel eloquent like this :

```
$query = $this->item->select('a.*','b.attribute_code')
    ->from('items as a') 
    ->join('attr_maps as b','b.number','=','a.number')
    ->groupBy('a.number');

foreach($param as $key => $value) {
    $query = $query->having($key, '=', $value);
}

$query = $query->paginate(10);
```

My $param is dynamic. It can change

If `$param` is `array('number'=>'1234')`, it works. No error

If `$param` is `array('description'=>'test')`, there exist error : `Unknown column 'description' in 'having clause'`

I tried all fields in the table items. Only the number field works. Apparently because the number field is group by

How can I make all field in the items table works if using `having`?

Comment: Why not using just "where"? remember from sql having is used only for agreggation. I believe you're trying to filter not aggregate.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir I using mysql

Comment: @RogerRodriguezTexido My case is quite complicated. My case is actually like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241536/how-can-i-convert-conditional-aggregation-mysql-to-laravel-query. See `$param`. It's dynamic. So I need to using having to filter it

Answer (score 1):

The `HAVING` clause is used in the `SELECT` statement to specify filter conditions for a group of rows or aggregates. The `HAVING` clause executed after `SELECT`, so if you apply `HAVING` on columns which is not in `group by` or not in `aggregate` function then it will work as where, which is no use because select clause is already executed. And i think just because of that eloquent may throw exception, not sure though.

What you can do, check your `param` key if it is in `group by` fields then apply having if not then add it as `where` condition like this.

```
$query = $this->item->select('a.*','b.attribute_code')
    ->from('items as a') 
    ->join('attr_maps as b','b.number','=','a.number')
    ->groupBy('a.number');

foreach($param as $key => $value) {
    if($key== 'number'){
        $query = $query->having($key, '=', $value);
    }else{
        $query = $query->where($key, '=', $value);
    }
}
```

you can check here [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Comment: Seems `where` doesn't work after `groupBy`. `where` should it be placed before `groupBy`

Comment: The order is irrelevant, Laravel takes care of that. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Laravel's Eloquent ORM is active-record inspired and very database centric.

In the end, it's mainly because [`having` is an sql concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)) which is used to filter rows in aggregate results.

In short, you're dealing with patches to problems in the SQL language which the Eloquent ORM has not abstracted away.

Comment: My case is quite complicated. My case is actually like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241536/how-can-i-convert-conditional-aggregation-mysql-to-laravel-query. See `$param`. It's dynamic. So I need to using having to filter it

Comment: Oh, apologies, I seem to have answered the question you were asking rather than the problem you're facing. Anyway, having is made for aggregate functions. Number works because it's used as group by, for the rest you should use `where`.

Comment: No problem. Whereas if I try run in mysql query in database gui, it works. This just not works in laravel eloquent

Comment: Maybe you should try and look at the actual query (or queries) Eloquent is running. As far as I know you can't just select all columns from a table in an aggregate query without grouping them all, so there's possibly some magic going on.